# How to get SDL error as integer, enum or something else, except string?

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

I was working on a project using `SDL2` and `C`. When it opens images as `SDL_Surface`, sometimes when the filename provided is not an image, it would return error message saying that `Unsupported image format`. I currently use `SDL_GetError()` to print the error message, but would like to print my own error message instead of the error message provided by `SDL_GetError()`. How can I get the SDL error as an `integer` or `enum` or some other value, so that I can handle the error on my own?

Comment: It doesn't seem possible. The global SDL error is a static variable (`SDL_global_error`), not accessible from outside, and the only function/macro (`SDL_GetErrBuf()`) to get it is not exposed via headers https://github.com/emscripten-ports/SDL2/blob/master/src/SDL_error.c